# 'Trying to get property of non-object' when using WP_Query with 'fields' => 'ids'

Tags: wp-query

In an attempt to speed up my query, I'm using the following arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'fields' => 'ids',
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

While this does return an array of IDs as expected, I keep getting multiple `Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-includes/query.php` notices. This happens even when I have nothing inside my `while` other than `the_post()`:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
endwhile;
endif;
```

Is `the_post()` causing this? Any idea why I'm getting these notices?

Comment: What's the `fields` entry? Never heard of that before. Does it work when you remove that?

Comment: The `fields` => `ids` option returns an array of post *ids* rather than post *objects*, which (apparently) makes the query faster.

Comment: I see. That explains Milo's answer then (apparently)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`the_post` places the next post object from `$query->posts` in the global `$post` and calls `setup_postdata`, which assumes `$post` is a post object, as it tries to access member vars of that object, which is where the errors come from.

In this case `$posts` is just an array of IDs instead of post objects. If you want to iterate over the results, you can do a `foreach` on `$posts`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()):
    foreach( $query->posts as $id ):
        echo 'ID: ' . $id;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Spot on. The documentation for `the_post()` that I found didn't cover what it *actually did* in great detail, so I didn't realise it was attempting to access other vars.

Comment: While using `'fields' => 'ids'` may be faster on the query, it still has to go and fetch each post individually one at a time, which ends up adding a 2+ queries per post instead of just 1 (to get meta when you need it).

Comment: I did however submit a ticket to Trac which could alleviate the object errors, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a *huge* object cache with each post already stored in it, but even then it's really not optimal.

My ticket involves allowing setup_postdata ($wp_query->setup_postdata) to accept a Post ID, which would be handy if you only had IDs to work with. Still, getting IDs from a WP_Query 'fields' => 'ids' should be avoided at all costs if you intend to use WP template tags and/or get post data for all posts returned by WP_Query.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30970

Comment: If you did intentionally set posts_per_page to 1, I could see the ticket I've submitted could actually help you, because 'fields' => 'ids' would be quite quick, and the overhead is small if you have object caching enabled as the post may likely already be cached so get_post may actually be faster versus getting the full objects from the DB without 'fields' => 'ids'

Comment: @ScottKingsleyClark indeed, *if you intend to use WP template tags and/or get post data for all posts returned by WP_Query* then you're doing it wrong by using the `fields` argument. I assumed that OP just needed IDs and not full post objects. I thought that was reflected in the example code I provided, but perhaps I should have been more explicit.